# What pool catters to multiple alternate currency?

Tags: mining-pools

I want to mine alternate coins. I am looking for pools that support many of the coins here so I do not have to keep changing pools.

Answer (score 1):

try www.multipool.us they have a server which does multiple currencies in a day(depending on their profits)